# Python Multiprocessing: Loop through files to export data

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have written a code to extract data from a particular file format and export to *.csv file. I am doing this in loop for multiple files of same format. In this way I am only using one core of my computer (loading <15%) and by this way it takes long time to convert all the files I have. So I was trying to do multiprocessing so that my jobs will be done in parallel using full CPU power.

The below code I have written doesn't work in loops and would like to get advice on how do I do it in a right way.

Thanks in advance.

This is my complete code.

```
from pathlib import Path
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import os
import multiprocessing as mp

# Provide path to import and export data
import_path = r'C:\Data_Analysis\New_folder.' # data folder path 
export_path = r'C:\Data_Analysis\New_folder\Export' # CSV file export folder path

def multiprocessing_func(filenames):

 for filenames in Path(import_path).rglob('*.dxz'):   
 # Call DCOM object
  dw = Dispatch("Dewesoft.App")

 # Initialise the software
  dw.Init()

  # Load data file
  dw.LoadFile(filenames)

  # Change the channels property
  for i in range(0, dw.Data.AllChannels.Count):        
      dw.Data.AllChannels.Item(i).Exported = True
      dw.Data.AllChannels.Item(i).CustExportRate = 1

# Extract file name from imported file
  ExpName = os.path.basename(filenames)
  ExportName = os.path.splitext(ExpName)[0]

# Export data to CSV file
  dw.ExportData(7, 1, export_path + "\\" + ExportName + ".csv")

# Close the software
dw = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
  pool = mp.Pool()
  pool.map(multiprocessing_func, Path(import_path).rglob('*.dxz'))
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
```

Comment: You are not doing parallel processing, you are just creating a single process to read from file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple bug left in your script: You do not yet use the `filenames` argument of  `multiprocessing_func`. That's why you see no multiprocessing at the moment.

Calling `Pool` with default number of processes is fine, the python docs state

> processes is the number of worker processes to use. If processes is None then the number returned by os.cpu_count() is used.